# Search Results with googlemaps

Tags: search, forms, google-maps

I have made a custom search for houses.

The problem is that I have to show in the search results page, a "googlemaps" with the points at which there is a house, according to the search results obtained.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard, it's hard to answer this in detail with this little details.
Do you need to pinpoint a single house?
Will you use an address or will you use latitude and longitude?

My suggestion would be to take a look at this excellent [Google Maps Plugin for jQuery](http://gmap.nurtext.de/). jQuery is part of any WordPress installation, so you wouldn't need to install anything else. Additionally this is quite easy to load.

Below a quick example of how I've implemented this, using custom fields to store both a latitude and a longitude. But you could just as well get an address returned as a search result and add that:

```
    <!--Map implementation-->
<?php
//Quick conditional to make sure I don't show maps on items where no two coordinates are available  
        if (($wtr_latitude) && ($wtr_longitude)) { ?>
<div id="map" style="width:680px; height: 203px; background-color:grey;"></div>   
<script type="text/JavaScript">                                                     
      $("#map").gMap({
          controls: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                      controls:               ["GSmallZoomControl3D", "GScaleControl"],
                      maptype: G_PHYSICAL_MAP,
                  markers: [{ latitude: "<?php echo $latitude; ?>",
                              longitude: "<?php echo $longitude; ?>",
                              popup: false }],
                          zoom: 10 });              
   </script>
 <?php } ?>
```